# implementing 2:1 multiplexer with 5 variable equation

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

This is my boolean equation: (P+Q)S+(R+T)S' (2^5)
How can I get to a 2:1 multiplexer using its truth table?

I tried to reduce the truth table to a 16 bit table and then to an 8 bit then to 4 then to 2, but I didn't get to any result.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce two auxiliary/intermediate variables:

```
A := P + Q              (A := P or Q)
```

and

```
B := R + T              (B := R or T)
```

You multiplexer expression is now

```
Z := A*S + B*S'         (Z := A and S or B and not S)
```

The truth table:

```
S  A  B  Z
----------
0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1
0  1  0  0
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
1  1  0  1
1  1  1  1
----------
```

Truth table in minimized form showing only rows with output 1:

```
S  A  B  Z
----------
0  X  1  1            'X' = don't care
1  1  X  1
----------
```